# How to query variables of other recipes via Bitbake tasks or functions?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to query variables defined in other recipes from my own function. Let's say recipe `xxx.bb` defines `PACKAGES = "yyy"`, how can I query `PACKAGES` from another recipe's function. I presume it could be possible via some `d.getVar("BPN")` magic. Usually I only seem to have access to my current recipe's `bb.data_smart.DataSmart` realm, but maybe it's possible to access `DataSmart` realm of other recipes. Anyone knows how? Or is there another way to access the data?

Comment: It is not possible. Recipe data is local to the recipe.
What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

As qschulz mentioned, this is not possible due to the local scope of each recipe.